# iOS navigation bar loses transparency when I set BarTintColor

Tags: ios, navigation, uinavigationbar, translucency

I'm rather new to iOS development, and have been breaking my head for the last days on creating a translucent navigation bar with a custom tint.

My current status:

- I've created a new project with a red view embedded in a navigation view, which is embedded in a tabbar.
- In the red view, i position an image partially behind the navigation view, to prove that translucency is working. *It works.*
- I change the bar tint color to white:

  ```
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
  ```
- The translucency is gone.  The image doesn't shine trough anymore. So i tried:

  ```
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent: 0.5]];
  ```
- Still not working.

Any advice on how to fix this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the backround of the navigationBar to be translucent, you can try :

```
[(UIView*)[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setAlpha:0.5f];
```

I found this here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/12389579/3626094

Otherwise, if you want the whole navigationBar translucent, including the buttons and title you can try:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.5f;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

I found this here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/6959527/3626094

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.5];
```